# Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetRolesForUser'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Strange errors are happening after backing up a SQL Server database to another server. The application has also been migrated. It is an ASP.NET MVC4 application.

I get the following error:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetRolesForUser'. 

Line 1:  @{
Line 2:      bool visible = false;
Line 3:      if (User.IsInRole("Administrador"))
Line 4:      {
Line 5:          visible = true;
```

The stored procedure is there, the database is the same, and the server has the same name so I presume the connection string should not be changed.

How can I trace the errors to find what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure the schema is the same? You might have created your tables and stored procedures under a different schema than `dbo` (I think default setup will create them under a schema that is named the current user name)

Comment: Yes... they are from dbo schema.

Comment: Did you migrate your database user accounts as well?  The database restore would create the user in the database but not on the server.  Do you know if the user accounts are orphaned?

Answer (score 1):

Check the connection string being used by ASP.NET Membership. This is the connectionStringName attribute in the membership provider section. Then refer to the connectionStrings section to see the actual connection string as per that name.

eg.

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
  <clear/>
  <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider,       System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
connectionStringName="THE_CONNECTION_STRING_NAME"  applicationName="/"/>
</providers>
</membership>
```